# Whats so special about the Landweber method that it justifies an individual name for ordinary gradient descent

Tags: numerical-methods

the Landweber Method is imho nothing more than gradient descent on a specific quadratic form.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landweber_iteration

so why does it warrant an own name?

Comment: Just speculating, but maybe when it was introduced there was less awareness of gradient descent so the equivalence wasn't widely recognized. Or maybe when discussing methods for solving $Ax=b$ people needed a shorter name than "using gradient descent to minimize the norm of the residual".